# Reading data from RadioLink R12DS receiver by S-BUS protocol

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application

My goal is pretty simple: I wanna read information from my RadioLink R12DS receiver by S-BUS protocol using desktop console application, written on C#.

I use AT9S transmitter blinded together with receiver in 12 channel mode. I tested it on Pixhawk flight controller. Everything was fine there, no any problem with retrieving data.

I designed a console application based on investigated articles. Here is a couple most valuable of them:

http://forum.fpv.kz/topic/303-frsky-x8r-sbus-v-cppm-konverter-na-arduino/ https://github.com/bolderflight/SBUS

My application receiving byte stream from a COM Port, one by one, and tries catch message header "0x0F", but it doesn't appear.

The SBUS protocol uses inverted serial logic with a baud rate of 100000, 8 data bits, even parity bit, and 2 stop bits. The SBUS packet is 25 bytes long consisting of:

- Byte[0]: SBUS Header, 0x0F
- Byte[1-22]: 16 servo channels, 11 bits per servo channel
- Byte[23]:
- Bit 7: digital channel 17 (0x80)
- Bit 6: digital channel 18 (0x40)
- Bit 5: frame lost (0x20)
- Bit 4: failsafe activated (0x10)
- Bit 0 - 3: n/a
- Byte[24]: SBUS End Byte, 0x00

A table mapping bytes[1-22] to servo channels is [included](https://github.com/bolderflight/SBUS/blob/master/extras/bit-mapping.pdf).

Here is listing of my code:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var availablePorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        using(var port = new SerialPort(availablePorts[0], 100000, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.Two))
        {
            port.DataReceived += PortOnDataReceived;
            while(true)
            {
                if(!port.IsOpen)
                    TryReconnect(port);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }


    // HANDLERS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static void PortOnDataReceived(Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        if(SbusConverter.TryReadMessage(serialPort, out var messageBuffer))
        {
            var message = SbusConverter.Convert(messageBuffer);

            Console.WriteLine(message.ServoChannels[0]);
        }
    }

public static Boolean TryReadMessage(SerialPort serialPort, out Byte[] messageBuffer)
    {
        const Int32 messageLength = 25;
        const Int32 endOfStream = -1;
        const Byte sBusMessageHeader = 0x0f;
        const Byte sBusMessageEndByte = 0x00;

        messageBuffer = new Byte[messageLength];

        if(serialPort.BytesToRead < messageLength)
            return false;

        do
        {
            var value = serialPort.ReadByte();
            if(value == endOfStream)
                return false;

            if(value == sBusMessageHeader)
            {
                messageBuffer[0] = (Byte)value;
                for(var i = 1; i < messageLength; i++)
                {
                    messageBuffer[i] = (Byte)serialPort.ReadByte();
                }

                if(messageBuffer[0] == sBusMessageHeader &&
                   messageBuffer[24] == sBusMessageEndByte)
                    return true;
            }

        } while(serialPort.BytesToRead > 0);

        return false;
    }
```

I have thoughts in my head and I want ask one question here.

It's possible, that RadioLink use different, modified or their own S-BUS implementation, than Futaba and I found no proper documentation yet.

Anybody, who experienced in that field, any suggestions please. It seems, I am stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: Also I should make a note, that I am already tried to read byte stream by external libraries, C++ Arduino libraries too. That's why I have thought about different protocol implementation.

Comment: make sure you get at least 25 bit before processing.  Your while loop may not work because TCP has keep alive message which is a data message with zero bytes.  TCP specification allow routes and server to split and combine message.  So you could be sending 25 bytes and then receive two messages with 12 & 13 bytes.  You can send two messages 12 bytes and 13 bytes and then receive one message of 25 bytes.  You code has to be able to handle these cases.

Comment: "make sure you get at least 25 bit before processing" - yes, of cause. "TryReadMessage" function responsible fo that. I think, the previous commentary is out of topic, because I am using RS-232 (COM Port), not network. But, really, this function may be not fully debugged because I have stopped at receiving header byte. It seems it's unavailable in receiving data stream. It might be different than "0x0f", which described in documentation.

Comment: Most of what I said for tcp still applies to serial port.  Windows events move both TCP and Serial port data very similar using timers.  The timers do not care where end of data is located.  Use should be using no parity if you have 8 data bits and use one stop bit.  Also make sure you turn off hardware and software handshaking.

Answer (score 0):

I made some investigations of received data stream and uncovered that RadioLink devices uses "0x1F"   as a frame start byte insted of "0x0F". Another connection and message properties are the same.

```
var availablePorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        using(var port = new SerialPort(availablePorts[0], 100000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
        {
            Handshake = Handshake.None
        })
        {
            port.DataReceived += PortOnDataReceived;
            while(true)
            {
                if(!port.IsOpen)
                    OpenPort(port);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: C# message parser implementation sample available here: [link](https://github.com/merkator2160/Arduino/blob/master/src/SbusListener/Sbus/SbusConverter.cs)

Comment: Also I should make a note. There are some "shaking/shifting" of message frame in current implementation, which happens sometimes. I have not discovered source of the problem yet maybe un proper COM port connection speed or something else. I added Kalman filter on each SBUS channel, but the situation doesn't become better. I think the source of the problem laying somewhere else. Maybe I have just misunderstand something. If somebody have any ideas please add it here.

Answer (score 0):

Two years too late, but I just noticed you have 1 stop bit set, instead of 2, in the code of your answer. That could probably explain 0x1F instead 0x0F and otherwise shifted data.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same kind of operation, intercepting Sbus signal from a herelink radio controller, so far I discovered a shift in the data and my start byte is recognised with the value of `0x1E`. Moreover the data seems super noisy when looked at the oscilloscope, some 1 might be missing because of the poor quality of the signal and the ramp from 0 to 1.